# Closing/hiding divs with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello & Happy New Year  to all.

My question concerns fading in and hiding divs with js. My page has 2 or 3 divs. Currently, when I click on a div, it fades in. When I click on a second div, it also fades in and the first div hides.

When I click on a div twice, I want it to close. I can open the second div and it will close the first but the second div is still open and I can't work out how to close it. You can see here on this image, I click on the 'country' div and it opens http://prntscr.com/2g4dmw, then I click on 'quality' and it opens http://prntscr.com/2g4duf but I can't close it. I use this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("div #industry").click(function(){
                $("div #stars").hide();
                $("div #countries").hide();
                $("div #industries").fadeIn('500');

            });

        $("div #star").click(function(){
                $("div #industries").hide();
                $("div #countries").hide();
                $("div #stars").fadeIn('500');
            });

        $("div #country").click(function(){
                $("div #industries").hide();
                $("div #stars").hide();
                $("div #countries").fadeIn('500');
            });

    });
```

I appreciate any help if u need more info feel free to ask.

Comment: Did you look into jquery ui accordion?

Comment: Dont know what u mean I have not maded this

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here. You want to click an element to make it visible? But how would you want to click it if it is not allready visible?
Can you create a fiddle with what you have so far?

Comment: Look into this. http://jqueryui.com/accordion/   I'm not sure, but I think this is what u are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/n8rwA/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#industry").click(function(){
            $("#stars").hide();
            $("#countries").hide();
            $("#industries").slideToggle( "slow" );

        });

    $("#star").click(function(){
            $("#industries").hide();
            $("#countries").hide();
            $("#stars").slideToggle( "slow" );
        });

    $("#country").click(function(){
            $("#industries").hide();
            $("#stars").hide();
            $("#countries").slideToggle( "slow" );
        });

});
```

You can use toggle function or slidetoggle.

Comment: Tnx I will use this bcs it easy :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are closing the whole div, whereas you should have a structure like so for each section:

```
<a href="#" id="countryLink">Countries</a>
<div id="countries"></div>
<a href="#" id="industryLink">Industry</a>
<div id="industries"></div>
<a href="#" id="stars">Stars</a>
<div id="stars"></div>
```

and then bind to the clicks of the links not the divs themselves, that way the links remain there so you can click on them again to open it.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#industryLink").click(function(){
            $("div #stars").hide();
            $("div #countries").hide();
            $("div #industries").fadeIn('500');

        });

    $("#starsLink").click(function(){
            $("div #industries").hide();
            $("div #countries").hide();
            $("div #stars").fadeIn('500');
        });

    $("#countryLink").click(function(){
            $("div #industries").hide();
            $("div #stars").hide();
            $("div #countries").fadeIn('500');
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

H i,

**Consider this markup**

```
 <div class="contentcontainer">
  <h3>Country</h3>
    <div class="content">
       I am the content for country
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="contentcontainer">
  <h3>Industry</h3>
    <div class="content">
       I am the content for Industry
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="contentcontainer">
  <h3>Stars</h3>
    <div class="content">
       I am the content for Stars
     </div>
 </div>
```

Your **javascript** can then be shortened to:

```
    $(".contentcontainer").on("click", function() {
       $(".content").each(function() { $(this).hide(); });
       $(this).find(".content").show();
    });
```

- The click event will hide all other content panels first, then show the one you "clicked".

Answer (score 0):

Good answers above so I don't think another specific answer here is needed. I'd like to generally deconstruct the problem to look at why some of the answers were provided. It sounds like you have two interaction needs:

1. User can unhide or hide a DIV

   1. DIV can be re-(un)hidden
2. When a hide/unhide action is taken, all the other DIVs hide

Breaking it down can help clarify to yourself what you're trying to do, and make it easier to solve the problem.

The original implementation dealt with #2 as well as half of #1. When we look at the answers, you're seeing various solutions which deal with each separately (with more or less refactoring from your original code).

@Amel Salibasic's suggestion solves 2, then 1, for your specific case. @Rob Sedge's would probably be more robust, as it also solves 1.1.; if you're using the div also as the trigger, once you hide it the DIV shouldn't be visible in the browser to click and show it again. So, you should generally use something else to trigger this sort of effect (like a title).

Generally, try breaking out the individual steps of how the full interaction should work, consider if they can be grouped (hide/unhide the target div are two sides of the same coin) and then try to solve them.